# Accessing old Room database in Room Migrations

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration

I have updated my database structure and I moved the data contained in one DB (let's call it DB 1) into a table of another DB (let's call it DB 2).

How do I get an instance of the old DB (DB 1) in room migration to move data from DB 1 to the new table created in DB 2?

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options assuming that both databases are on the device:-

You can open it as an SQLiteDatabase using the `[openDatabase][1]` method, obviously closing it when done.

- This method doesn't allow direct copying/moving via SQL you would extract into a Cursor and then load from the Cursor.

Alternately you can [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) the old to the new ensuring that you [DETACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_detach.html) after the data has been moved. Noting that use of the `schema name` can be crucial when accessing the old db (attached).

- This does facilitate direct copying using SQL.
- note that DATABASE is the path to the database AND that it should be enclosed in single quotes. e.g. `main_sdb.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + other_sdb.getPath() + "' AS other");` *main_sdb being a SupportSQliteDatabase instance (as passed to the Migration) in this case the path of the database being attached is retrieved from another such instance. The schema name is **other***

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. I have a question though! Room is not running migrations since this is just a new database I think. How can I force it to run migrations? The only other solution I can think of is doing it manually in the onCreate() of the MainActivity but that doesn't feel right to me!

Comment: @LorenzoBenevento You can force a migration by incrementing the database version number. You could also use either the onCreate or onOpen callbacks. The former would run only when the database is first created. The latter would run every time the database is opened and would require checking the status e.g. are there any rows in the new table.