# copy column from one table to another during migration in room kotlin

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room, database-migration

I need to copy values from one column in one database and copy them to another newly created column in another database. I was able to create a new column using auto-migration. But got stuck with the manual migration.
This is the code for migration inside the catalogue db class

```
val migration3To4 = object : Migration(3,4){
override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE 'Favorites.db' as 'fav")
                database.execSQL("UPDATE 'Catalogues' SET 'favorite' = (SELECT 'favorite' FROM 'fav' WHERE Catalogues.code = fav.itemCode")
                database.execSQL("DETACH DATABASE 'fav' ")
            }
    }
```

This needs to happen when 'code' from the Catalouge database is the same 'itemCode' from the Favorite database. the SQL command seems fine to me (I don't have any experience with it), but the database is empty when the app opens. What am I doing wrong here?

**Updated**

```
        private val migration3To4 = object : Migration(3,4){
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                val attachDbPath = (database.path?.let { File(it).parent }) + File.separator + "Favorite.db"
              
                    database.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '$attachDbPath ' AS fav")
                    database.execSQL("UPDATE 'CatalogList' SET 'favorite' = (SELECT 'favorite' FROM fav.FavoriteList WHERE CatalogList.code = fav.FavoriteList.itemCode")
                    database.execSQL("DETACH DATABASE 'fav'")
                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the path to the database file not just the file name when attaching. e.g. [Accessing old Room database in Room Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440329/accessing-old-room-database-in-room-migrations/68447115#68447115)

That short answer was extracted from this more long winded answer which goes into more detail and also alternatives [Room - Using external SQLites as well as internal DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495308/room-using-external-sqlites-as-well-as-internal-db/56512638#56512638)

**Extra 1**
Re comment:-

> but still database gets cleaned up

Assuming that the attach has worked then you UPDATE query has a potential flaw. If a **code** in the CatalogList does not have an equivalent value in the **itemCode** then the **code** will be set to NULL. Obviously if the FavoriteList table is empty or there are no itemCode's that match the code's then the value for ALL rows in the CatalogList will have NULL for the favorite.

You may wish to provide a WHERE clause for the UPDATE that ensures that only rows where the code is an itemcode are updated. The following demonstrates (but without attaching):-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CatalogList;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FavoriteList;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CatalogList (favorite TEXT, code TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FavoriteList (favorite TEXT, itemCode TEXT);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO CatalogList VALUES('FAV1','A'),('FAV2','B'),('FAV3','C'),('FAV4','Z');
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO FavoriteList VALUES ('NEWFAV1','A'),('NEWFAV2','B'),('NEWFAV3','C');
UPDATE CatalogList SET favorite = (SELECT favorite FROM FavoriteList WHERE CatalogList.code = FavoriteList.itemCode);
/* RESULT OF FIRST UPDATE */
SELECT * FROM CatalogList;
/* Clear the CatalogList table*/
DELETE FROM CatalogList;
/* Repopulate the CatalogList as before the first update */
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO CatalogList VALUES('FAV1','A'),('FAV2','B'),('FAV3','C'),('FAV4','Z');
/* AMENDED UPDATE to ONLY update the code IF the itemcode exists in the FavoriteLIst */
UPDATE CatalogList SET favorite = (SELECT favorite FROM FavoriteList WHERE CatalogList.code = FavoriteList.itemCode) WHERE code IN (SELECT itemCode FROM FavoriteList);
/* RESULT OF THE AMENDED UPDATE */
SELECT * FROM CatalogList;
/* CLEANUP TEST ENVIRONMENT*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CatalogList;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FavoriteList;
```

- **Note** the above is without ATTACH

The Result of the first update:-

[image]

The Result of the amended update:-

[image]

i.e. as there was no itemcode Z in the favoriteList table then the favorite that has the code Z has been left unchanged (as opposed to be changed to NULL).

- **This assumes that the ATTACH was successful**

**Extra 2**

You may wish to consider testing to see if the database has in fact been attached, here's part of your migration along with 2 functions that will output some potentially relevant information to the log:-

```
    val migration3To4 = object: Migration(3,4) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            val TAG = "MIGRATE_3_TO_4"
            val attachDBPath = database.path?.let { File(it).parent } + File.separator + "Favorite.db"
            Log.i(TAG,"Database File ${attachDBPath} exists = ${doesDatabaseFileExist(attachDBPath)}")
            database.execSQL(" ATTACH DATABASE '$attachDBPath' AS fav")
            DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(database.query("SELECT pragma_database_list"))
            logRowsInFavorites(database,"favoriteList",TAG)
                ....
        }
    }

    fun doesDatabaseFileExist(pathToDB: String): Boolean {
        return File(pathToDB).exists()
    }
    fun logRowsInFavorites(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase, table: String, tag: String) {
        val csr = database.query("SELECT count(*) FROM $table")
        var rowsFound=0
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rowsFound = csr.getInt(0)
        }
        csr.close()
        Log.i(tag,"Number of Rows in the $table table is $rowsFound")
    }
```

**EDIT/ADDITONAL**

Re the comment:-

> Write Ahead Logging (WAL) mode cannot be enabled or disabled while there are transactions in progress.  Finish all transactions and release all active database connections first.

The issue is that when the Migration is called, there is a transaction on the database and thus ATTACH is hard to use (if even possible). If you try ending the transaction it fails saying that there isn't one.

What I would suggest is that you instead following the "use an external database" as was previously linked. That is instead of attaching the Favorite.db database, that you extract the data from it  as a separate database a copy the data from the FavoriteList table to a like named table in the CatalogList database. The FavoriteList table is then available (an can be dropped when done with).

As an example, the following has been tested:-

```
    val migration3To4 = object: Migration(3,4) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            generateFavouritesListTable(database,"Favorite.db") /*<<<<<<<<<< use the Favorite.db as external db not attached */
            val TAG = "MIGRATE_3_TO_4"
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE CatalogList ADD COLUMN extra TEXT") /* For the Migration to be invoked the schema must be changed so hence this */
            //database.endTransaction() //<<<<<<<<< does not work as it says there is no transaction to end??
            //val attachDBPath = database.path?.let { File(it).parent } + File.separator + "Favorite.db" //<<<<<<<<<< not needed 
            //Log.i(TAG,"Database File ${attachDBPath} exists = ${doesDatabaseFileExist(attachDBPath)}") //<<<<<<<<<< could be used if wanted
            //database.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '$attachDBPath' AS fav") // cannot use
            //DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(database.query("SELECT * FROM pragma_database_list")) //<<<<<<<<< not needed as not attaching
            logRowsInFavorites(database,"favoriteList",TAG) //<<<<<<<<<< optional BUT NOTE favoritelist now exists
            database.execSQL("UPDATE OR IGNORE CatalogList SET favorite = (SELECT favorite FROM FavoriteList WHERE code = FavoriteList.itemCode)")
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FavoriteList;") // probably wise to delete but not actually required
            //database.execSQL("DETACH DATABASE 'fav'") //<<<<<<<<<< cannot/should not use
            //database.beginTransaction() //*<<<<<<<<<< should not be used, but in theory if ending the transaction above, start one to be ended
        }
    }

    fun generateFavouritesListTable(roomDb: SupportSQLiteDatabase, sourceDbName: String) {
        /* Get the path to Favorite.db */
        val favoriteDbPath = roomDb.path?.let { File(it).parent } + File.separator + sourceDbName
        /* Open the Favorite.db database as an SQLiteDatabase */
        /* Note that it is irrelevant that the database is a Room database, it is ALWAYS an SQLiteDatabase */
        val favoriteDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(favoriteDbPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
        /* prepare the new NON-ROOM table to hold the data from Favorite.db */
        /* Just in case drop the non-room table */
        roomDb.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS favoriteList;")
        /* Create the non-room table */
        roomDb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favoriteList (favorite TEXT, itemCode TEXT);")
        /* extract the data from the FavoriteList table into a Cursor */
        val csr = favoriteDb.rawQuery("SELECT favorite,itemCode FROM favoriteList;",null)
        /* Prepare to use the SQliteDatabase convenience insert method */
        val cv = ContentValues()
        /* Loop through the extracted Cursor inserting into the non-room table */
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            cv.put("favorite",csr.getString(0))
            cv.put("itemCode",csr.getString(1))
            roomDb.insert("favoriteList",OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE,cv)
        }
        /* Finished with the Cursor so close it */
        csr.close()
        /* Finished with Favorite.db so close it */
        favoriteDb.close()
    }
```

- the abundance of comments purposefully included.

**However** the above does not address the issue in regard to the result being "cleaned up". If the table has no rows UPDATE will neither insert or delete rows, that issue has to be elsewhere.
Perhaps note that for the Migration to be invoked you not only have to increase the version number BUT you also have to change the schema   (hence why in my test I added a column via the `ALTER TABLE`), thus there would appear to be other code than in the code in your question.

**Results of Example*/

When the App is run as Version 3 the following code:-

```
    val sb = StringBuilder().append("DATABASE VERSION IS ${db.openHelper.writableDatabase.version}")
    for (cl in dao.getAllFromCatalogList()) {
        sb.append("\nFAVORITE = ${cl.favorite} CODE = ${cl.code}")
    }
    Log.i("DBINFO",sb.toString())
```

Results in :-

```
I/DBINFO: DATABASE VERSION IS 3
    FAVORITE = FAV1 CODE = A
    FAVORITE = FAV2 CODE = B
    FAVORITE = FAV3 CODE = C
    FAVORITE = FAV4 CODE = Z
```

- version 3 (for testing Favorite.db exists and is populated with 3 rows for itemCode A B and C NOT Z)

After the Migration the log shows:-

```
I/DBINFO: DATABASE VERSION IS 4
    FAVORITE = NEWFAV1 CODE = A
    FAVORITE = NEWFAV2 CODE = B
    FAVORITE = NEWFAV3 CODE = C
    FAVORITE = FAV4 CODE = Z
```

- i.e. FAV1/2/3 have been updated as per the favorite value (NEWFAV1, NEWFAV2 and NEWFAV3 respectively) for the associated/respective code (A,B and C) in the FavoriteList table.

Comment: thanks a lot! i will take a look at those links now)

Comment: i dont think second link is related with my question. in the first link tho: `main_sdb.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + other_sdb.getPath() + "' AS other");`  how can I get other_sdb there so I can get its path?

Comment: i cant use getDatabasePath() because in db class there is no context

Comment: @jane **If** you are using the standard database location then bar the file name itself the path would be the same.  So you don't need the context. You could use something like `val attach_db_path = (database.path?.let { File(it).parent }) + File.separator + "Favorites.db"`

Comment: thanks, i will try that now.
one more question: as table name in SQL command, should use the file name in the storage (like Favorite in Favorite.db) or should I use tableName at Entity annotation ( as in `@Entity(tableName = "FavoriteList")`) ?

Comment: @jane The table name will be the table name as per the database. If you use `@Entity ....` and you the defined the entity via the `entities` parameter of in the `@Database` annotation (the only reason for using the `@Entity` annotaion) then Room will expect the table to exist in the Room database i.e. You will get an error because the table is not in the database. So you should be using `SELECT favorite FROM fav.the_table_name` *(where the table name is obviously replaced with the actual table name)*.

Comment: thankss got it, so when using UPDATE, I should also use tableName as in Entity because it already knows which database is being updated(as it's passed in the migrate function) right?

Comment: @jane as per *Tables in an attached database can be referred to using the syntax schema-name.table-name. If the name of the table is unique across all attached databases and the main and temp databases, then the schema-name prefix is not required. If two or more tables in different databases have the same name and the schema-name prefix is not used on a table reference, then the table chosen is the one in the database that was least recently attached.* from https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

Comment: @Jane So main.Catalogues or Catalogues and fav.the_table_name or the_table_name if it is a name unique to favorites.db (not also in the Room database).

Comment: got it! thanks for your time and answers. i really appreciate it). but still database gets cleaned up when the app opens. i updated the question with the code changes. could you please take a look?

Comment: @jane try removing the space in `'$attachDbPath '`  (before the final single quote).

Comment: Thanks Mike, for such a lengthy answer. I really appreciate your help. 

but when I said _but still database gets cleaned up_  i didn't only mean favorite and code columns. that database has a lot of columns and all of them got deleted entirely. now I'm testing extra 2 to check if i correctly attach the database. can you explain in `database.query("SELECT pragma_database_list"` what  pragma_database_list means? should i change it with my table name or?

Comment: it gives this error on dumpCursor function `no such column: pragma_database_list (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT pragma_database_list`  I tried changing pragma_database_lsit to table name and column name, but still didn't work

Comment: Sorry should be `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(database.query("SELECT * FROM pragma_database_list"))`you may wish to refer to https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_database_list

Comment: oh got it. i debugged it without the functions, it throws this error on attach database line `Write Ahead Logging (WAL) mode cannot be enabled or disabled while there are transactions in progress.  Finish all transactions and release all active database connections first.`  even tho there is no transactions happening at the moment. so it cant attach the database from the start

Comment: @jane I have added, what I believe is the basis of a solution (actually the not *related link* as such). See the **EDIT/ADDITIONAL** section for the changes. In short ATTACH cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks again for such a detailed answer) I will try the new method and and share my updates here. thanks again